# Regex for OR ing two range regexes

Tags: java, regex

I need a regular expression for occurrence of 0 to 7 alphabets OR 0 to 7 digits.

Eg: Match : `1234`, `asdbs`

Not Match : `123456789`, `absbsafsfsf`, `asf12`

I tried `([a-zA-Z]{0,7})|([0-9]{0,7})`, but this does not work.
Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: Can you show what a sample of matches as they might look in a file/variable? Otherwise it's hard to know what you're doing wrong

Comment: Insead of `{0,7}`, like to use `{1,7}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do it: `^([a-zA-Z]{0,7}|[0-9]{0,7})$`

Comment: I had not used the string start and string end tags and also messed up with grouping.

Answer (score 1):

You are using OR incorrectly. The structure is `(match1|match2)`, but you currently have `(match1)|(match2)` Your regex should be:  `([a-zA-Z]{0,7}|[0-9]{0,7})`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this `Regex`:

```
String regex = "\\p{Alnum}{0,7}";
```

The regex `\p{Alnum}` includes all the alphabets and digits.

Comment: Several problems: (1) `\p{Alpha}` only matches letters; you're thinking of `\p{Alnum}`.  (2) You need to escape the backslash for the Java string literal. (3) There should be no space in `{0,7}`. (4) This won't work anyway, because the OP wants all letters **or** all digits, not a mixture.

Comment: Oh oh Sorry! I have updated, Yes you are right. Thanks! BTW the problem 2 and 3 is not a problem, because the Intellij IDE automatically do add and remove something, but you are right. If you use Intellij you will know what will happens while doing copy and paste...

Comment: Yes, This wont work as I needed all numbers OR all alphabets.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pattern `\b([a-zA-Z]{1,7}|[1-9]{1,7})\b` to match:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String input = "- 1234, asdbs  123456789, absbsafsfsf, asf12";
        Pattern  pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b([a-zA-Z]{1,7}|[1-9]{1,7})\\b");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
        List<String> listMatches = new ArrayList<String>();

    while(matcher.find())
    {
        listMatches.add(matcher.group(1));
    }

    for(String s : listMatches)
    {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1234
asdbs
```